# Kotlin DialogFragment editText editable always null

Tags: android, android-edittext, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

So, I'm using Kotlin extensions which is straightforward, but I can't get string from edittext

here is my code:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

    val v = activity.layoutInflater
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog_group, null)

    v.add_group_button.setOnClickListener(addListener)

    return AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
            .setView(v)
            .create()
}

private var addListener: View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener {

        val groupNameInput: String = view?.group_edit_text?.text.toString()

    }
```

when I'm pressing add button `groupNameInput` always returns null why?

Answer (score 2):

So finally I figure it out — on Dialog Fragment view will always be null, because its never created, but it's created and added to dialog view which means I need to call:

```
dialog.group_edit_text.text.toString()
```

Instead of:

```
view.group_edit_text.text.toString()
```