# DialogFragment SignIn with Firebase edittext must not be null error

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have created a xml with 2 edittext and 1 image and inflated in DialogFragment. Than i created 3 buttons. But only my positiveButton isn't working.

```
class SignInDialogFragment: DialogFragment() {
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private val tag1:String="className"
private lateinit var intent:Intent
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    Log.d(tag,"Tıklandı. 1")
    intent=Intent(activity,SignUpActivity::class.java)
    auth = Firebase.auth
    return activity?.let {
        val builder= AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(),R.style.MyThemeOverlay_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)
        val inflater=requireActivity().layoutInflater
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in,null))

           .setPositiveButton(R.string.signIn) { dialog, id ->
               Log.d(tag1, "edittext2= ${eposta.text}")
               auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                   eposta.text.toString(),
                   sifreGir.text.toString()
               )
                   .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                       if (task.isSuccessful) {
                           Log.d(tag1, "signInWithEmail:success")
                           val user = auth.currentUser
                           updateUI(user)
                       } else {
                           Toast.makeText(
                               requireContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                           ).show()
                           updateUI(null)
                       }
                   }
               //Giriş eylemleri
           }
            .setNeutralButton(R.string.sign_up) { dialog, which ->
                startActivity(intent)
                //Kayıt ol sayfaseına göndersin
                dialog.dismiss()
                Log.d(tag1,"Kayıt ol' a geçti")
            }
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel) { dialog, id ->
                //İptal et
                dialog.cancel()
                Log.d(tag1,"Dialog dismissed!")
            }
        builder.create()
    }?:throw IllegalStateException("Aktivite boş olamaz.")

}
```

And this is my Logcat Error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: eposta must not be null
> at com.ebookfrenzy.beaotis.SignInDialogFragment$onCreateDialog$$inlined$let$lambda$1.onClick(SignInDialogFragment.kt:31)
> at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:160)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

I found this [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47285180/kotlin-dialogfragment-edittext-editable-always-null). I got the idea but i can' t use it like that it gives me Unresolved reference error. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add below lines to your code

```
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sign_in,null)
builder.setView(view)
```

Replace

```
eposta
```

with this

```
view.eposta
```

Comment: You are welcome. Kindly upvote the answer too.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have enough karma to do that.

Comment: Oh, No issues. Thanks